# Hexadecimal Computations in Perl

Tags: perl, xor, unpack

I have a string of ASCII characters. I convert this to hex string using the unpack function.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str="hello";
my $value=unpack("H*",$str);

print $value,"\n";

**output:** 68656c6c6f
```

Now, lets say, I want to use this output as a string of hex bytes, read one byte at a time and perform some computation on it and store the output in another variable.

For instance,

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str="hello";
my $value=unpack("H*",$str);

my $num=0x12;
my $i=0;

while($i<length($value))
{
    my $result.=(substr($value,$i,2)^$num);
    $i+=2;
}

print $result,"\n";

**output:**

Argument "6c" isn't numeric in bitwise xor (^) at test.pl line 13.
Argument "6c" isn't numeric in bitwise xor (^) at test.pl line 13.
Argument "6f" isn't numeric in bitwise xor (^) at test.pl line 13.
8683202020
```

The output is incorrect and also there are several warnings.

If we take the first hex byte of the string, "hello" as an example:

```
68 xor 12 = 7A
```

However, the output shows it as 86. The output is incorrect and also I am not sure how 
it got an output of 86.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: You're using warnings, yet you try to access $result outside of its scope?

Answer (score 6):

If something is in hex, it is necessarily a string, since hex is a *human-readable representation* of a number. You don't want a string; you want a series of numbers, where each of those numbers is the numerical value of the char. You could use [`ord`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ord.html) to get the number character by character, but `unpack` also provides the means:

```
my @bytes = unpack 'C*', $str;
```

Do the processing you want:

```
$_ ^= $num for @bytes;
```

And reconstitute the string:

```
$str = pack 'C*', @bytes;
```

The above three combined:

```
$str = pack 'C*', map $_ ^ $num, unpack 'C*', $str;
```

You can also do it as follows:

```
my $mask = chr($num) x length($str);
$str ^= $mask;
```

Comment: Thanks, This is good but I think only for ASCII Characters. I am processing a binary file, and this is the reason, I need to use the hex representation of the bytes instead. If I understand it correct, your method, will get the ASCII value for each character and perform an operation on that. I want to do it in hex.

Comment: @Neon Flash, You are mistaken. `^`, `ord` and `chr` know absolutely nothing about ASCII. They all deal with arbitrary characters, which is a fancy word for number.

Comment: @Neon Flash, And I shall repeat: No, you don't want to do it in hex (`$num = "12";`), you want to do it with numbers, machine integers (`$num = 0x12;`).